# Return value after emit event in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to run an event, and then one of the childs, will be able to cancel the event.
In vanilla-javascript is is easy
`form.onsubmit=function () {return false}`

The question is, how to do it in `AngularJS events`

This is the code in outside controller

```
$scope.$broadcast('user-want-to-leave',function(value){
     if(/*Check is inner controler want to cancel the navigation*/){
          do_not_navigate()
     }
     else {
         navigate()
     }
})
```

this is a code in inside controller

```
$scope.on('user-want-to-leave',function(e){
    // The inner contoller, want to cancel the event.
    e.cancel=true
    return false;           
   }
})
```

---

**Bonus:** This is is any e.stopPropagation() in Angular event, like in jQuery events?

In other words: How I return an value from an `$on` function to the `$broadcast` function?

[image]

**Update:** Thank you. This is the JSFidlle working: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21727/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope,$timeout) {
        $timeout(function(){
     var e=$scope.$broadcast('event')
     alert(e.defaultPrevented)
    })
}

function MyCtrlInner($scope) {
    $scope.$on('event',function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        })
}
```

Comment: Angular use jQuery then yes you can use all the Jquery feature, you have just to import the module

Comment: How I now if the inner-controller returned false to my event?

Comment: @StefanoSaitta, not all  :-) [jqLite implement a few functions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: from doc for broadcast: [_The event cannot be canceled._](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast)

Comment: what triggers this in the first place? Really not clear what your specific problem is

Comment: @charlietfl, sample in post with `$broadcast`

Comment: @Grundy but that doesn't reflect anything to do with stopping propagation from a UI event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Angular [$scope.$on method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) calls the event handler and passes an event object to it that has a stopPropagation() method.

> The event listener function format is: function(event, args...). The event object passed into the listener has the following attributes:
>
> - targetScope - {Scope}: the scope on which the event was $emit-ed or $broadcast-ed.
> - currentScope - {Scope}: the scope that is currently handling the event. Once the event propagates through the scope hierarchy, this property is set to null.
> - name - {string}: name of the event.
> - stopPropagation - {function=}: calling stopPropagation function will cancel further event propagation (available only for events that were $emit-ed).
> - preventDefault - {function}: calling preventDefault sets defaultPrevented flag to true.
> - defaultPrevented - {boolean}: true if preventDefault was called.

**UPDATE**

The original question title was about events that are emitted, not broadcast...and the edited question appears to be about two-way communication between the event handler and the original scope? To answer that question: the event object also has references to the current and original scopes. See above.

Comment: [_available only for events that were $emit-ed_](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)

Comment: Should he be using the `preventDefault()` method instead of `cancel`?

Comment: But how the parnet scope, (who call $broadcast), knows if the event preventDefault flag is true?

Comment: event.defaultPrevented